# Dell Workstation t7910 and FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, hardware-compatibility

I want to install FreeBSD on a Dell Workstation t7910. This workstation has a nVidia Quadro graphics card and two Xenon processors.

Would FreeBSD recognize the hardware on a Dell Workstation t7910?

Comment: FreeBSD doesn't has any problem with Xeon.But you can issue nvidia in FreeBSD ML.